# Is there a way in Wireshark to save only the packets in the listing window?

Tags: wireshark, packet-sniffers

I would like to know if there is a way to save only No., Time, Source, Destination, Length field in Wireshark? I do not need the contents, I want it in plain text as well. Is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: Check this [topic](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/25936/how-to-export-packet-summary-to-text-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those are your only columns configured in Wireshark, then after loading a capture file you achieve this as follows: [`File -> Export Packet Dissections -> as "Plain Text" file... ->`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChIOExportSection.html#ChIOExportPlainDialog), then in the *Packet Format* section, select only the *"Packet summary line"* (and optionally *"Include column headings"* if you wish) and deselect everything else.  Choose a filename and click *"Save"*.

If you have other columns displayed, you can either hide or remove them first or create a separate [profile](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCustConfigProfilesSection.html) with only the columns of interest displayed.

You can also accomplish this with [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html), Wireshark's command-line companion.  There are several ways to do this, so select a method that best fits your needs.  Here are some examples:

**Using specified Wireshark columns:** (Note: `-e _ws.col.No.` doesn't work)

```
tshark -r file.pcap -T fields -e frame.number -e _ws.col.Time -e _ws.col.Source -e _ws.col.Destination -e _ws.col.Length > file.txt
```

**Using named fields:** (assumes IPv4 addresses in Source and Destination columns)

```
tshark -r file.pcap -T fields -e frame.number -e frame.time -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e frame.len  > file.txt
```

**Rely on Wireshark's configured columns:**

```
tshark -r file.pcap  > file.txt
```

**Rely on Wireshark's configured columns for a particular profile:**

```
tshark -r file.pcap -C profilename  > file.txt
```

**Using column option:** (First on Windows, then on *nix)

```
tshark -r file.pcap -o "gui.column.format:\"No.\",\"%m\",\"Time\",\"%t\",\"Source\",\"%s\",\"Destination\",\"%d\",\"Length\",\"%L\""  > file.txt

tshark -r file.pcap -o 'gui.column.format:"No.","%m","Time","%t","Source","%s","Destination","%d","Length","%L""  > file.txt
```

(Run `tshark -G column-formats` for more column options.)

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thank you!